# Some reports not showing in dashboard

Tags: civireport, dashboard, dashlet

As of version 5.6.0, some of our reports are no longer showing up in people's dashboards as a dashlet option.  The reports have "Available for Dashboard" set and permissions seem right, I even set them to allow all people to see them.  But they still do not show up in the dashboard.  We have about 13 reports as dashlets, which doesn't seem like a big number.  I can't figure out why these won't show up. Anyone have an idea of what may have changed or something we need to configure?

Some screenshots:

[Report Settings](https://forwardedgeint-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/paulbarmaksezian_forwardedge_org/EZR4KzXA_4FEqrSGPakz3JUBZChF2UbeOVyUyyJ4vzpG7g?e=BM3ZFt)

[My Dashboard](https://forwardedgeint-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/paulbarmaksezian_forwardedge_org/EQjFbCePLeFMkx92VPbt_nYBuQ1mDxxloQu101dDBY-RIQ?e=mCSUSZ) (I'm the drupal admin, have all permissions)

If any other screenshot will help, happy to send them.

Comment: Can you add some screenshot? Eg dashboard, report, etc?

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion, I updated the original post with a couple of screenshots, hope that helps. If you need something else to track it down, I'm happy to provide what I know.